# SQL: extract the last word

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
id | cars
1  | John's Honda
2  | Andrew's red lexus
3  | James has a bmw
```

I need to just get the last word of the "cars" column that shows the actual "car" name
I have tried the followings but I don't get the desired output

```
select substr(cars, -1)
from t
```

the code above just shows me the last charater of the column. Later, I tried the following:

```
select split(cars, ' ')[offset(1)] 
from t
```

however, I got the "Array index 1 is out of bounds (overflow)" error. Can anyone help how this can be achieved with bigquery?

Answer (score 0):

Consider below simple approach

```
select *, 
  array_reverse(split(cars, ' '))[offset(0)] as brand
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Note: there are really many ways to accomplish your case - so anoher one would be `regexp_extract(cars, r'\b(\w+)$') as brand`

Comment: Thank you! It worked!